# How to run Internet Explorer Selenium Driver in compatibility mode and also "Run as Administrator"?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, browser-automation

How can i start Selenium IE driver in compatibility mode and also how to "Run as Administrator" [Run As Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YMU.png)?

We have a legacy system that require these two settings. I have my test in JAVA running on Selenium grid.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does this help any? https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6894

Comment: The article talks about running as different user accounts. I want it to run as administrator. I attached the image to the original post.